# JPanel overriding methods don't work

Tags: java, swing, background, jframe, jpanel

// This works!

```
JPanel background = new JPanel();
background.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
background.setBounds(0,0,this.getSize().width,this.getSize().height);
add(background);`
```

// Ihis method doesn't work! Why ? And the classic method `setBackground(Color.BLACK);` has the same problem

```
JPanel background = new JPanel()
{
    @Override
    public void setBackground(Color bg){
        super.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    }
    @Override
    public void setBounds(int a, int b, int c, int d){
        super.setBounds(0,0,this.getSize().width,this.getSize().height);
    }
};
add(background);
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: i want to set the background for a JFrame

Comment: Then why do you override those methods?

Comment: Why would you want to override methods in first place?

Comment: You overrided the methods but have you called them then.

Comment: i don't want to declare too much objectes, i want somthing like this, but it doesn't work: `add(new JPanel()
        {
            @Override
            public void setBackground(Color bg){
                super.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            }
            @Override
            public void setBounds(int a, int b, int c, int d){
                super.setBounds(0,0,this.getSize().width,this.getSize().height);
            }
        }); `

Comment: May be the issue is with the absolute size of the `JPanel`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definite issue you are going to encounter will come from calling `setBounds` method.
Call `setBackground` for your panel and just add it to `JFrame` by calling `add` method. `JPanel` will be added on center of `JFrame` by default since default layout for `JFrame` is a `BorderLayout` and it will perfectly fit without of calling `setBounds`. There is absolutely no need to complicate things by overriding any method.

This:

```
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestPanel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.add(panel);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            //frame.pack();
            frame.setSize(400, 300);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

...will work perfectly.

Comment: Plus one to this one. 1. For getting rid of setBound. 2. For not entertaining this overly pointless idea of overring setBackground.

Answer (score 0):

Though you have ovverriden methods, you haven't called them.

Comment: This should be comment

Comment: No need to call `setBackground()` method. It works fine without method call.